# Using neural network to predict next outcome

Tags: javascript, node.js, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I am struggling to understand how to use neural networks to predict some values.

As I have understood, I can train my neural network with some time series.

So if I have, for instance, the day-to-day quotes for a specific stock, I can train the network with these values.

But if I have the day-to-day quotes as a vector `[42, 12, 20, 53, 18]` and I want to predict the next value, wouldn't it just be a linear regression problem with formula `Y = 0.7X + 31.1`, yielding `26.9` as the next (6th) value?

Is neural networks only useful when the output relies on many inputs? Can someone show me a working example of how to predict the next outcome in a time series that shows that it's more useful to use neural networks rather than multivariate regression?

I have, for instance, looked at [synaptic.js](https://github.com/cazala/synaptic), but they don't provide any simple examples to predict outcomes.

I am very new at neural networks, so I am sorry if this question is really stupid :-D

Comment: You could check out [Neataptic](https://github.com/wagenaartje/neataptic), it offers some more examples!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Recurrent Neural Network to such task in a following manner:

1. **Input:** as an input take a sequence of a stock prices without the last one.
2. **Output:** as an output take a sequence of a stock prices without the first one.
3. **Topology and network details:** build a recurrent neural network (e.g. by using *GRU* or *LSTM* units) in a way that given an input it must predict the next step. So for example feeding `[42, 12, 20, 53]` as an input should produce the `[12, 20, 53, 18]` as an output (I'm using an example sequence which you gave).
4. **Prediction step:** if you want to predict the next outcome of your network - simply feed your network with the sequence you have and take the last output as a prediction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a dataset consisting of, for example, 2 dimensional values and you know from plotting etc. that best matching function to your data is a linear function, in fact a straight line, you can simply apply linear regression to fit your data or an single perceptron (which is the same).

Since your function template, your model, for linear regression is `f(x)=mx+b`, where `m` and `b` are the adjustable parameters for an algorithm such as gradient descent.

If you know that the function to match your data, for example, must be a polynomial of an higher degree than a linear function, you could apply multivariate regression with a more complex model or an neural network. The function model's complexity is in case of an neural network defined by the size and count of the hidden layers.

I'm sure it's dependent on the problem which algorithm outperforms the other.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I have a training set `[{input: [volume, open], output: [close]}, ...]` where `volume` is the number of shares traded, `open` is the opening price, and `close` is the closing price. Wouldn't an RNN be sufficient to compute this? How do I know how many hidden layers I need?

Comment: I don't have much experience with RNNs but you could take a look at NARX networks: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_autoregressive_exogenous_model

Comment: I know that matlab offers this architecture for time series prediction. I've tried to solve similar problems as you do with a basic MLP and I never got sufficient results but I can tell you that you have to figure out the count and size of your hidden layers by try and error. There is no verified way to figure those out upfront. I would train several instances of your network parallel and compare those to one another to see which setup provides the best results. Hope it helps you!